# How to remove 'value.0' from the top of a bar in a bar chart in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, bar-chart

I received this bar chart [Please click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcrD2.png)after executing a code below. But on the top of my bar each values are represented by value.0 . I just wanted to ask how could i remove .0 . I am a beginner of pandas and i appreciate any help. Thank you .

```
  df=pd.DataFrame([11,62,82,120,125,141,192,38],index = ['10-20','21-30','31-40','41-50','51-60','61-70','71-80','81-90']) 

    ax = df.plot(kind='bar',stacked = False, colormap = 'Paired',alpha=0.75, rot=0)
    ax.legend_.remove()
    for p in ax.patches:
            ax.annotate(np.round(p.get_height(),decimals=0), (p.get_x()+p.get_width()/2., p.get_height()), ha='center', va='center', xytext=(2, 10), textcoords='offset points')
    plt.ylabel('Number of co-occurrences ')
    plt.title('Occurences by Age Group')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: this works for me, what version numpy, pandas and matplotlib are you using? My numpy version is 1.11.1, pandas 0.19.1

Comment: Try to cast the float as integers - `np.round(p.get_height(), decimals=0).astype(np.int64)`

Comment: Perfect Nickil. Thanks for the help. works pretty fine